# customizing Eureka Server dashboard

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

How do I customize the spring cloud eureka dashboard. I have to customize the look and feel and also provide restricted access only to admin. Also, how to configure actuator endpoints of all my eureka client which are registered under the dashboard.

Comment: did you find any solutions how to do this?

Comment: please refer to https://programmer.group/customize-your-own-eureka-management-interface.html